# How to download dynamodb backup to localhost

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a backup of DynamoDB table, I want to download it to my localhost in order to restore it on local dynamodb instance. Couldn't find any documents, every tool I found like `dynamodump` creates on-demand backup and then downloads it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How exactly do you have the backup?

Comment: @hunterhacker, on-demand backup, has Backup ID, name, ARN

Comment: So you (for purposes here) have a pointer to the backup. And the backup is in a proprietary format and not directly accessible to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do an Export to S3 and then you’ll have direct access to the objects in S3. Hopefully that satisfies your need?

Comment: No actually, guess i'm going to end up using dynamodump.

Answer (score 1):

The backup which you state belongs to DynamoDB and not directly accessible to you, it's only purpose is to restore to DynamoDB tables in the cloud.

You have 2 options

### 1. [Export to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html)

As @hunterhacker stated you can do an export to S3 and then download the data from there.

### 2. [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)

A more cost effective solution is to write a local script which does a `Scan` or if there is a large amount of data a parallel Scan and store the data locally